# For each row, how to separate an interval and attribute a value based on other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame like this:

```
df1 = {'id': [1, 2], 'aa': [2, 5],'ab': [50,40], 'ba': [6, 4],'bb': [40, 60],'type_of_a': ['A','B'],'type_of_b': ['B','C'] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)
df

    id  aa  ab  ba  bb  type_of_a   type_of_b
0   1   2   50  6   40  A           B
1   2   5   40  4   60  B           C
```

For each line, I would like to create a new column 'type_of_c' which will allow me to define the type of section, either:

"A_Nan", "Nan_A", "A_B", "B_Nan", "Nan_B" with the coordinates of 'type_of_a' and 'type_of_b'.

Desired data frame :

```
    id  aa  ab  ba  bb  type_of_a   type_of_b   ca  cb  type_of_c
0   1   2   50  6   40  A           B           2   6   A_NaN
1   1   2   50  6   40  A           B           6   40  A_B
2   1   2   50  6   40  A           B           40  50  A_NaN
3   ...
```

I have made a schema to be more comprenhensible:

[image: my schema]

Comment: so you want some kind of outer merge?

Comment: @mozway, yes, that's it